# Ubuntu takes much time to boot cause of cleaning orphaned inodes

Tags: boot, 16.10, debugging, inode, gnome-activity-journal

So usually my system boots almost instantly (I have a fast SSD)

but for some time now after some freezes that seem to now to have disappeared it used to take like 2 minutes or so maybe more to the ubuntu boot screen (which is also low res.. I am talking about the purple screen which says "UBUNTU" in the center and has some white dots that turn red while the system is loading) usually this image was High res and it lasted for one to five seconds max... now I wait like two full minutes for it to go away..

After ctrl+alt+f5 during that screen I see that its trying to repair the journal and clear orphaned inodes...

I understand this to happen when system freezes and doesnt shutdown properly but for the last week or so I boot and use the system without freezes or issues and I shut it down normally from the unity bar>shutdown ...

So what could be the problem or how can I make it stop trying to clear those orphaned inodes on every boot...

I use ubuntu 16.10

Comment: You are describing a serious problem that should be fixed (not bypassed) to prevent data loss. Run a SMART test on your storage drive.

Comment: I dii run it no issues... I think that got triggered by a freeze that happened cause of a bugged driver in the ubuntu base or graphics card (nvidia) but now it stopped occurring